# (Py)Qt5: How to update selection when current item has been set programatically

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

Usecase: I have a `QListWidget`.  When the user selects any row, I want to reset the current item and selection to row 3:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListWidget

app = QApplication([])
l = QListWidget()
l.setSelectionMode(QListWidget.SingleSelection)
l.addItems(list('abcde'))

def slot(current, previous):
    # sm = l.selectionModel()
    l.blockSignals(True)
    l.setCurrentRow(3)
    l.blockSignals(False)
    # sm.select(l.currentIndex(), sm.Select)  # Does not work
    # sm.setCurrentIndex(l.currentIndex(), sm.Select)  # Does not work

l.currentItemChanged.connect(slot)
l.show()
app.exec()
```

The example above sets row three as current row but keeps the selected row to the one that the user clicked.  I already tried various combinations of `QItemModel.select()` and `QItemModel.setCurrentIndex()` and similar stuff, but nothing worked.  I also found no answers on Google or the Qt forums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using blockSignals in this case is a double-edged sword because I think you're using it to avoid an infinite loop. but this also does not generate that the model is updated, besides that it is unnecessary since `setCurrentRow()` only updates if it is different from its previous value avoiding that problem.

The solution is to use `QTimer.singleShot()` to update the change:

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
l = QListWidget()
l.setSelectionMode(QListWidget.SingleSelection)
l.addItems(list('abcde'))

row = 3

def onCurrentRowChanged():
    QTimer.singleShot(0, partial(l.setCurrentRow, row))

l.currentRowChanged.connect(onCurrentRowChanged)
l.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: the logic does not change if the `currentRowChanged` signal is changed to `currentItemChanged`.

Comment: Thx, my real use case was a bit more complex, but I could apply your solution there as well. Seems like the `QTimer.singleShot(0, ...)` enables Qt to compute all the necessary selection changes before I change the current row again.